# Send JSON data from handheld app to wearable

Tags: android, wear-os

If I need to send plain json should I use `MessageClient` or `DataClient` with `Assets`?

Comment: you should use MessageClient

Comment: you can refere this blog for more understanding

Comment: @jayshah you forgot the link

Comment: this link : http://twowords.io/communication-wear-mobile/

Comment: @jayshah it seems that MessageClient is for sending actions/command and not for row data or custom objects.